# How to display different database value in jsp page table side by side

Tags: jsp, jdbc, html-table

I have written a jdbc code  where I extract values from mysql table and show in jsp page. Values are showing on this page, but one below the another value. What I need is different values should be shown  side by side i.e. one next to the another.

Here's my jsp code:

```
    <%

      try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grandsho_register";
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "pwd");

   String sql = "select title,link,keyword,category,image,content from adminproduct       where category='Nokia'";
  st=connection.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
  while(rs.next()) {


  %>   


   <TABLE border="0" width="900">
<tr valign="top">
<td width="300" ALIGN=left>
    <div class="item_list">
    <iframe src = '<%=rs.getString("link") %>' frameborder = 0 height=250>    </iframe><input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="<%=rs.getString("keyword") %>" />

    </div>  </td>
    <td width="300" ALIGN=left>
    <div class="item_list">
    <iframe src = "here i need different table value" frameborder = 0 height=250> </iframe><input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="<%=rs.getString("keyword") %>" />

    </div>  </td>
    </tr>
  </TABLE>


    <%              }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
  if (st != null) {
    try {
    st.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    } // nothing we can do
     }
   if (connection != null) {
    try {
    connection.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
  } // nothing we can do
    }
   }
  %>
```

Here table has two columns, i want different values in these columns. Can anyone suggest me some solution?

Comment: Obviously the columns are the TD parts. So you should only have the TD in the while loop (once), not the whole table.

Comment: I sure hope your code is for demonstration purposes only. Accessing a database from a JSP was considered a bad practice for last 15 years or so.

Comment: @Olaf yes i know this is wrong , just for demo

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the while loop before the `table` tag, so you are defining two tables, just move the while loop inside the table before the `tr` tag

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
<TABLE border="0" width="900">
  <% while(rs.next()) { %>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td width="300" ALIGN=left>
      <div class="item_list">
        <iframe src = '<%=rs.getString("link") %>' frameborder = 0 height=250></iframe>
        <input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="<%=rs.getString("keyword") %>" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="300" ALIGN=left>
      <div class="item_list">
        <iframe src = "here i need different table value" frameborder = 0 height=250>  
        </iframe>
        <input type="hidden" name="keyword" value="<%=rs.getString("keyword") %>" />

      </div>  
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% }
</TABLE>
```

Comment: as per your solution values still showing one below the another (along with another column),what i need is to show these values in above mentioned two columns in a row.